# Encuesta: ¿permitimos las traducciones de contenido del sitio en inglés? ¿En qué condiciones?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Viendo que lo de las traducciones de contenido del sitio en inglés es un tema candente, me he decidido a crear una encuesta para tener la opinión de la comunidad resumida en un único lugar. En esta ocasión he optado por crear la encuesta usando los formularios de Google, por favor entrad y votad:

[**Encuesta sobre la traducción de contenidos del sitio en inglés**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gq_egveLVhGrDeUoThcdS9bI19YtNjOG5y4X3Q-7KxQ/viewform?usp=send_form)

[Resultados de la encuesta](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gq_egveLVhGrDeUoThcdS9bI19YtNjOG5y4X3Q-7KxQ/viewanalytics?usp=form_confirm)

No he incluído los siguientes puntos en la encuesta porque considero que ya estamos todos de acuerdo:

- El contenido original debe ser de calidad (si no, debe mejorarse al traducirlo)
- Las traducciones deben incluir siempre un enlace al contenido original
- No se permite el uso de traductores automáticos

Si tenéis alguna sugerencia para añadir respuestas a las preguntas de la encuesta o para mejorar las respuestas existentes, dejad un comentario o una respuesta a esta pregunta. También podéis sugerir más preguntas, junto con las respuestas propuestas.

**Actualización:**

Con posterioridad a la creación de la encuesta, JuanM ha publicado esta pregunta: [¿Cuándo es el mejor momento para traducir preguntas del sitio en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/236/23). Yo creo que dicha pregunta y esta encuesta no son una duplicada de la otra; la encuesta nos permite tener una visión *cuantitativa* de la opinión de la comunidad, y la pregunta una visión *cualitativa* con los argumentos de cada uno de nosotros.

Comment: relevante: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s
(y si no fuera por la encuesta, yo diría que duplicado)

Comment: La encuesta busca precisamente aglutinar en un único lugar la posición de la comunidad respecto a las traducciones (aunque por supuesto está bien usar Meta para discutir el tema más a fondo).

Comment: y donde se vota?

Comment: En el enlace que hay en la pregunta. :-)

Comment: Creo que tu idea es una buena iniciativa para poder llegar a consenso sobre este tema

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuando es el mejor tiempo para traducir preguntas del sitio en inglés?](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/236/cuando-es-el-mejor-tiempo-para-traducir-preguntas-del-sitio-en-ingl%c3%a9s)

Comment: Yo diría que no es duplicado sino complementario.

Comment: ¿Se llegó a consenso respecto si deben marcarse como wiki?

Comment: Hola @Konamiman, he visto los resultados pero no sé si se fijaron algunos criterios referentes a los resultados para actuar ante este tipo de situaciones. Por lo que puedo apreciar la mayoría consideran que habría que marcar como wiki de comunidad si no eres el autor de la pregunta/respuesta traducida literalmente (lo cual veo lógico) pero no sé si se llegó a fijar algún criterio.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero nótese que lo consulté hace poco y se llegó a la conclusión de que no, las traducciones no tienen que marcarse como wiki de comunidad: [¿Deben marcarse como wiki de comunidad las traducciones de contenido?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2657/83)