# ¿Cuándo es el mejor momento para traducir preguntas del sitio en inglés?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Traducir preguntas del sitio Stack Overflow en inglés nos proporciona preguntas/respuestas canónicas ya resueltas.  Sin embargo, ¿deberíamos traducirlas todas, unas pocas, o ninguna?

Answer (score 14):

**TL;DR**

> Se permite el traducir preguntas/respuestas del sitio en inglés pero
>   esperen hasta que terminemos el beta privado.

Hemos tenido mucha discusión sobre este tema.  Es importante que lean lo siguiente para saber la dirección que vamos a tomar en cuanto a las preguntas/respuestas de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Aceptaremos las traducciones de preguntas/respuestas canónicas de Stack Overflow en inglés siempre y cuando lo siguiente se tome en cuenta:

**1. Nuestra comunidad no este en Beta Privado**

No quiero que los nuevos usuarios que lleguen para el lanzamiento del beta público vean solamente preguntas canónicas del sitio en inglés.  Es para nuestro beneficio mutuo que ellos vean preguntas frescas, interesantes, y que estimulen el pensamiento.  Evitemos que la pagina principal se llene de preguntas con enlaces de referencia a Stack Overflow en inglés en las respuestas.  Esto robara su motivación y nos pondrá en luz negativa ante ellos.  Queremos dar una buena primera impresión.  Tenemos suficiente talento aquí que no necesita ayuda de preguntas externas.  Usemos nuestro conocimiento y curiosidad.

**2. Hemos dado suficiente tiempo para que los miembros publiquen las preguntas/respuestas primero**

¿Cuanto tiempo es lo suficiente? Usen su proprio criterio.  Como comunidad nueva, es de suma importancia el encontrar nuestra propia voz.  El traducir material previamente publicado nos afectara mas de lo que pensamos.  Con las traducciones se traen estructuras, puntos de vista, y lenguaje que tal vez no sea de la misma manera en que nosotros lo hiciéramos. Por eso, debemos dar suficiente tiempo para  que nuestros miembros pregunten/contesten con sus puntos de vista.

Por favor no quiten sus traducciones ya publicadas.  Déjenlas tal y como están. Lo dicho es en referencia al modo en que vamos a hacer las cosas de hoy en adelante.

**3. Las traducciones sean completadas en moderación y no para amasar reputación solamente.**

Esto será mas fácil saberlo cuando ocurra.  Si la intención es de abusar el sistema, será claro a la mayoría. Usen su discreción por favor.  Den oportunidad para que nuestra comunidad forme nuestras propias preguntas/respuestas canónicas.

Todos estamos aquí para ayudar.  El traducir material en inglés también es ayudar y por eso lo aceptamos.  Pero, no se debe usar en forma abusiva.

Por lo tanto, encontremos nuestra voz y animen a sus compañeros de comunidad a publicar contenido relevante a nuestros trabajos, nuestros proyectos, y nuestros intereses.  Este sitio va a ser un tremendo recurso a nuestra comunidad global así que tenemos la oportunidad y el privilegio de crear algo fenomenal. ¡Adelante!

Comment: Mmm bueno pero claramente no se están cumpliendo las condiciones, y lo de la minería de puntos es un hecho más que evidente. Entonces no tomamos ninguna acción al respecto de lo que ya está? Cuál debería ser el workflow para controlar estos episodios en adelante?

Comment: Me parece que es conveniente actualizar o bien publicar una nueva respuesta pues, si mal no recuerdo, ya llevamos más de un año en beta pública.

Answer (score 2):

Sugiero evitar la traducción literal de las preguntas y respuestas, en su lugar y a falta de inspiración propia, utilizar otras formas como lo son

- la adaptación

  - Una adaptación consiste en crear un texto que coincide en las ideas principales pero su expresión puede realizarse de forma distinta, generalmente considerando el público o las circunstancias vigentes. Es común que una adaptación incluya muchos elementos del texto original, pero no se puede calificar coomo una traducción fiel del texto original pues incluye *sufientes* elementos que lo distinguen.
- la inspiración

  - La inspiración se refiere al acto de iniciar un acto creativo el cual puede dar o no como resultado un texto. Es común que un texto inspirado en otro coincida en ideas y propósitos pero no en la forma.

Veáse también (artículos de Wikipedia)

- [Literatura](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/236/cu%C3%A1ndo-es-el-mejor-momento-para-traducir-preguntas-del-sitio-en-ingl%C3%A9s),
- [Guión adaptado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guion_adaptado)
- [Inspiración artística](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspiraci%C3%B3n_art%C3%ADstica)