# ¿Deben marcarse como wiki de comunidad las traducciones de contenido?

Tags: soporte, traducciones-de-contenido, wiki-de-comunidad

En los primeros días de SOes en beta, hubo mucho debate aquí en Meta respecto las traducciones de contenido proveniente de SO. Dado que hubo cierto aluvión de estas publicaciones, se vio que podía pervertir el sitio, servir como manera de conseguir reputación rápidamente, etc. Véase por ejemplo [¿Son aceptables las traducciones de preguntas de StackOverflow en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/46/83).

Juan M en [¿Cuándo es el mejor momento para traducir preguntas del sitio en inglés?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/236/83) dio unas líneas maestras, la mayoría de las cuales ya se superaron: ya no estamos en beta, ha pasado un tiempo y la gente ya tiene cierta reputación.

Ese mismo día Konamiman publicó [Encuesta: ¿permitimos las traducciones de contenido del sitio en inglés? ¿En qué condiciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/230/83) que, con una participación de unas diez personas, arrojó [unos resultados](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1gq_egveLVhGrDeUoThcdS9bI19YtNjOG5y4X3Q-7KxQ/viewanalytics) tendentes a favorecer la traducción limitada, solo en casos de pregunta-respuesta (no traducir solamente la pregunta) y marcando todo como wiki de comunidad.

Sin embargo, la publicación algo posterior [¿Qué es una publicación "Wiki de comunidad"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/317/83) indica claramente cosas distintas: que lo de marcar como wiki de comunidad no aplica para la mayoría de estos casos.

> ### ¿Las traducciones de publicaciones desde el sitio en inglés deberían convertirse en *Wiki de comunidad*?
>
> **No.** O mejor dicho: no, a no ser que la publicación lo merezca por su contenido, con independencia de que sea una traducción o no.
>
> Las traducciones de contenido desde el sitio en inglés [se permiten
> con mesura](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/236/23); es decir, las
> traducciones son bienvenidas si son útiles y de calidad, pero se
> espera que la mayor parte del contenido de nuestro sitio sea creado
> originalmente por sus usuarios.
>
> Convertir una publicación en wiki sólo porque sea una traducción y
> supuestamente el autor no merezca la posible reputación devengada
> tiene dos problemas:
>
> - Se desvirtúa el significado original del wiki, que de forma resumida es "contenido que puede beneficiarse de múltiples ediciones por parte
>   de múltiples usuarios a lo largo del tiempo".
> - Si una publicación es útil para la comunidad, no hay razón para que su autor no reciba reputación por ella. [La reputación mide la
>   confianza que tiene la comunidad en un
>   usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), y
>   aportar buenas traducciones es una forma válida de generar confianza.
>
> #### ¿Y si la publicación original ya es wiki?
>
> Aún así, eso **no** significa que la traducción deba ser también wiki.
> En el pasado, las publicaciones de Stack Overflow se convertían
> automáticamente a wiki si se cumplían ciertas condiciones (más de diez
> ediciones por parte del autor original, por ejemplo), pero [dicho
> mecanismo se
> suprimió](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947/136880); por lo que
> hay publicaciones que fueron convertidas a wiki sin que realmente
> tuvieran por qué serlo.
>
> En resumen: que una publicación deba ser wiki o no, no depende del
> hecho de que sea una traducción.

Mi pregunta pues es muy simple: ¿debemos marcar como wiki de comunidad las traducciones de contenido? ¿sería posible tener una respuesta oficial para alinear todos los posicionamientos?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con respuesta oficial?

Comment: Todas las traducciones que hice las marque como wiki de comunidad, porque mas allá de tomarme el trabajo de traducir, la respuesta no es mía. Para mi, eso debería seguir igual. Y ya no creo que haya que seguir traduciendo cosas del sitio en ingles.

Comment: No veo que haya muchas traducciones en este momento, ¿o las hay?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, al menos no de forma autoritaria, de forma voluntaria por cada uno como ya se hizo es lo mejor.

El wiki de lo comunidad fue creado para *donar* una respuesta a la comunidad de tal forma que se fomente la edición y se vayan agregando mas información valiosa a una respuesta, de esta forma no habría un único autor sino que la comunidad entera (más exactamente los editores) son los encargados de dar la respuesta.

El hecho de que no se gane reputación es un aspecto secundario, consistente en mi opinión con el hecho que hay varios autores, pero **no el objetivo principal**.

Las respuesta de traducciones mas allá de correcciones ortográficas, no tienen nada más que editarse, a no ser que se aumente la respuesta original con algo mejor pero eso lo hará el propio autor de la respuesta.

El solo hecho de no ganar reputación por no ser autor de original de la respuesta no me parece válido. El hecho de dar la solución independientemente de la forma (siempre y cuando sea legal (si se mantiene el enlace al contenido original)) es válido.

Me parece que el tema de la reputación por traducciones que hubo originalmente (y si acaso surgiera una nueva, cosa que no es común)  ya está cerrado y la respuesta orginal, es decir **No convertir a wiki** sigue siendo válida y vigente.

Comment: Impecable el argumento, gracias Carlos. Una pregunta: con _respuesta original_, ¿a cuál te refieres? ¿A la que referencio en mi pregunta de _¿Qué es una publicacion "Wiki de comunidad"?_ Mi punto al preguntar era también mostrar mi sorpresa por la inclusión de esa guía de uso cuando no pude encontrar discusiones previas que llegaran a esa conclusión.

Comment: Si, me refería a esa

Comment: Procedo pues a aceptar la respuesta. Si algún moderador o CM nos da una respuesta oficial ya lo cambiaría. Gracias.

Answer (score -4):

Voto para **SI** marcar las traducciones de contenido como wiki de comunidad.

---

**Respuesta corta**

Basicamente lo que deseo decir es que la reputación no es un número o calificación, la reputación es cuanto la comunidad confia en que realmente sé de lo que estoy hablando/escribiendo. Si no marcamos las traducciones como wikis de comunidad, estoy ganando confianza de parte de la comunidad por algo sobre lo que puedo saber o no, ya que **no hay manera de demostrarlo**. Para mi, eso no tiene sentido.

**Respuesta larga**

En el centro de ayuda, en el articulo [¿Que es la reputación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) dice claramente que:

> La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto la comunidad confía
>   en ti; se gana convenciendo a tus pares (los otros miembros de
>   es.SOcom) de que sabes de lo que está hablando.

Quisiera aportar **mi punto de vista** en esto. Es cierto, el articulo citado por fedorqui indica que las traducciones aportan buen contenido y eso genera confianza. Ahora bien, el hecho de que alguien confie en mi, es porque el conocimiento que aporte en la comunidad le sirvió para resolver su problema o para aumentar su propio conocimiento. Si bien la traducción es buena, ¿que pasaría si me hacen más preguntas en los comentarios? ¿Podría proporcionar más ayuda? ¿Eso generaría dudas en el sistema de reputación de SOes? Podría alguien pensar: **"¿por qué el/ella gano reputación (mi confianza hacia el/ella) por eso si no sabe de lo que esta hablando?"**

El problema de las traducciones es que no sabemos si el AO (Autor Original) realmente sabe de lo que esta hablando o solamente sabe traducir. Al marcar la traducción como wiki de comunidad el AO aun esta vinculado con la publicación (sale como pregunta/respuesta en su perfil) pero no recibe la reputación. Yo traduzco esto asi: **"Tienes crédito por lo que hiciste, pero no confiamos al 100% en ti en este tema específico"**, lo cual considero justo.

Si consideramos la situación opuesta, podemos afirmar que el AO estaría ganando reputación por sus conocimientos de inglés y no necesariamente (quizas si o quizas no, el problema es como saberlo) por sus conocimientos de la temática del sitio, lo cual considero un poco menos justo que la situación anterior.

Si el usuario si sabe de lo que esta hablando, encontrará mucho más fácil responder la pregunta con sus propios conocimientos en vez de traducir, y por lo tanto, es totalmente justo que reciba la reputación.