# ¿Es únicamente responsabilidad del OP traducir su pregunta?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Me topé con [una edición sugerida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/185456) a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/310480/i-need-to-improve-the-performance-of-dynamic-information-visualization-on-a-high) consistente en la traducción de la pregunta del inglés al castellano. Luego rechazé dicha edición ya que era una traducción automatizada (traducía `highchart` por `gráfico alto` cuando claramente se refería a la librería del mismo nombre), sin embargo me entró la duda si con haber revisado la traducción automatizada y corregir donde aplicase para dar más contexto hubiese sido suficiente.

¿Es válido traducir preguntas de nuevos usuarios o se les debería delegar a ellos esa responsabilidad, como gestores de la pregunta, ya que únicamente ellos sabrían el contexto de dicha pregunta?

Comment: Interesante, se rechazó pero luego el AP la aceptó.

Comment: @fedorqui qué hacer en este caso en que el usuario acepta la edición, incluyendo el error en `highchart`? Revertir sería una opción?

Comment: @JheymanMejia entiendo que la mayoría de la edición le ha resultado útil, por lo que mejoraría esa parte

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No es valido por varias cosas:

- no sabemos el contexto
- Podemos cometer errores por lo que quisieron decir en la traducción
- Y lo mas importante, no sabemos ni podemos asegurar (muchas veces) que hablen español.

Entonces, no, no es valido traducirlas, y mejor delegar dicha tarea a quien pregunto.

Comment: Correcto, de hecho yo rechacé dicha edición comentando: *No sabemos si OP habla español, lo mejor será indicarle que el traduzca*

Comment: Interesante el último punto, pues en muchos casos traducir puede ser una pérdida de tiempo: si no entiende el idioma, difícilmente podrá entender la respuesta.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, últimamente estoy viendo muchas preguntas en inglés, me parece que bastante más que la media. ¿Habrá pasado algo?

Answer (score -2):

Votos negativos, vengan a mí!

Yo considero totalmente aceptable traducir preguntas hechas en otro idioma siempre y cuando se cumplan las siguientes condiciones:

- Que quien traduzca se pueda expresar efectivamente nuestro idioma con jerga técnica, (alguien que traduce "how to store a Java Bean into a jar?" como "¿Cómo almaceno un frijol en una jarra? en Java" merece <strike>todo mi desprecio</strike> que le rechace la edición sin pensar)
- Que la pregunta sea útil ( o por lo menos interesante ) para la comunidad latina
- Que la pregunta tenga los detalles necesarios completos, es decir traducir una pregunta en la que quien pregunta no sabe lo que quiere ni ha puesto anda de efuerzo en vez de sumar, resta
- que no sea una traducción automática, eso lo puede hacer cualquiera y no (me) mereces reputación por ello

Un punto muy mío por ser algo quisquilloso:

- Que la traducción no contenga faltas garrafales de ortografía

### Justificación

Al menos en mi caso me pasó muchas veces que no hallaba las respuestas en español, y no sabía como buscarlas en otro idioma, así que en algún punto me aventuré a una comunidad extraña llamada "Stack Exchange" en la que no existía contenido en mi idioma, pero sí una comunidad muy estricta que supo aceptarme, y trató de ayudarme muy a pesar de que no hablaba su idioma y no tenía la suficiente capacidad como para hacerlo eficientemente en sus idiomas que manejaban en ese momento en sus distintas comunidades.

Stack overflow en español como podrán haber adivinado es una de las nuevas sub-comunidades de Stack Exchange, es compleja para muchos nuevos miembros, pero no por ello debe de dejar de ser inclusiva.

Algo que les recomiendo hacer cuando alguien pregunta en otro idioma es siempre poner un comentario con un hipervínculo apuntado a la comunidad de su idioma en caso de que exista, y si no existe.... no sean egoístas y traduzcan su pregunta, que no saben cuantas veces me salvaron las traducciones automatizadas de respuestas en otros idiomas que no sabía hablar o sé hablar a la fecha.

Ya si nada de lo anteriormente expuesto ayuda a convencerte, es una forma muy efectiva de darle puntos a quienes tienen poca reputación, es decir, para que tengan más privilegios y por consiguiente puedan colaborar más en la comunidad en las tareas que (creo que alguna vez se expresó) nos tienden a superar como la revisión de colas.

Comment: Interesante respuesta, sin duda. Sin embargo, el AP entiendo que se refiere a casos en que el usuario a publicado en SOes en inglés, no a al AP que ha ido a un sitio en inglés y viene a traducir aquí. Sobre lo que comentas, se debatió al principio del sitio, por ejemplo en [Encuesta: ¿permitimos las traducciones de contenido del sitio en inglés? ¿En qué condiciones?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/230/83)